# Laravel REST API - returning different content types based on accept header parameter

Tags: laravel, rest

One of my endpoints require to return a PDF file. Normally it is JSON by default.

Do you think it is good to use `if ($request->header('accept') === 'application/pdf')` to return the PDF file? Does it break the single responsibility?

What if I have a lot of exceptions like that? It'd be too complex to have a lot of if/else statements for a lot of methods. What would be your suggestions?

Comment: is it a BinaryFileResponse object?

Comment: I use laravel-pdf package and it directly returns an pdf. I am not totally sure about it's object type.

Answer (score 2):

You can create middleware and apply to a single endpoint or to a group of them. This would leave everything organized and easily manageable in the future.

Comment: Makes sense, but do I need to create different methods for each different type of response -to get rid of the statements-?

Comment: It depends on your application needs. If you support PDF, XLSV and other type of files I guess you would need for each one but I would wait (or ask) for a more experienced dev here

Answer (score 0):

set header for php with header function in that api at the last of response and for frontend side check header contentType on behalf of that do your remaining stuff

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a middleware and and add this to kernel.php at protected $middleware array and do this code in 'handle' function

```
  $response = $next($request);

  if ($response instanceof ClassNameFromWhichObjectIsMatch )
        return $response;

   // add other headers
   //  $response->header($key, $value);

   return $response;
```